# How do I move all file with specific extension to a specific directory?

Tags: linux

How do I move all `*.exr` files to their respective 2048x567 directory ?

```
abc1/:
2048x567   xyz1.exr  xyz3.exr  xyz5.exr  xyz7.exr  xyz9.exr
xyz10.exr  xyz2.exr  xyz4.exr  xyz6.exr  xyz8.exr

abc2/:
2048x567   xyz1.exr  xyz3.exr  xyz5.exr  xyz7.exr  xyz9.exr
xyz10.exr  xyz2.exr  xyz4.exr  xyz6.exr  xyz8.exr

abc3/:
2048x567   xyz1.exr  xyz3.exr  xyz5.exr  xyz7.exr  xyz9.exr
xyz10.exr  xyz2.exr  xyz4.exr  xyz6.exr  xyz8.exr

abc4/:
2048x567   xyz1.exr  xyz3.exr  xyz5.exr  xyz7.exr  xyz9.exr
xyz10.exr  xyz2.exr  xyz4.exr  xyz6.exr  xyz8.exr

abc5/:
2048x567   xyz1.exr  xyz3.exr  xyz5.exr  xyz7.exr  xyz9.exr
xyz10.exr  xyz2.exr  xyz4.exr  xyz6.exr  xyz8.exr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
for dir in */; do
    echo mv "$dir"/*.exr "$dir/2048x567"
done
```

If the output looks good, remove the `echo` command